# Still seeing lock wait timeouts when deleting from large tables using primary key chunking

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a distributed application that logs millions of records to MySQL. Sometimes it's a million a day, or a week, depending on the user.

I recently re-wrote a "purge" system that automatically deletes outdated records. It runs every 12 hours and purges data based on rules the user setup. Since the database can often contain 50+ million records on average, I designed the query to use [primary key chunking](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).

Each delete query only scans a limited number of rows by their primary key. From my understanding, this reduces the number of locks needed by "containing" the other where conditions. The next delete query then runs a few seconds later.

However, many of our users still see "lock wait timeouts" and they always point back to the purge queries.

```
DELETE FROM prism_data WHERE prism_data.id >= 7564001 AND prism_data.id < 7568001 AND prism_data.epoch <= '1388566847'
```

Here is a portion of the engine status report:

```
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 458, OS thread handle 0x7efed0c62700, query id 779832 localhost 127.0.0.1 prism updating
DELETE FROM prism_data WHERE prism_data.id >= 7564001 AND prism_data.id < 7568001 AND prism_data.epoch <= '1388566847'
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 37 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 606 n bits 1272 index `epoch` of table `prism`.`prism_data` trx id 208A7E lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 52d7d976; asc R  v;;
 1: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
```

Just so you have it, here's the schema of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prism_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `epoch` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `action_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `player_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `world_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `z` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `block_id` mediumint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `block_subid` mediumint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_block_id` mediumint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_block_subid` mediumint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `epoch` (`epoch`),
  KEY `location` (`world_id`,`x`,`z`,`y`,`action_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Increasing the lock wait timeout usually helps, but surprisingly, reducing the range of records scanned per purge query doesn't seem to make a difference. some users don't have access to change mysql settings. Is there anything I can do to improve how we're deleting records to avoid causing lock wait timeouts?

**Update** Additional info per comments:

One of our users reported this error:

```
[13:43:47 INFO]: [Prism]: Database connection error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
[13:43:47 WARN]: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
[13:43:47 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
[13:43:47 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)
[13:43:47 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)
[13:43:47 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
[13:43:47 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
[13:43:47 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2620)
[13:43:47 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1662)
[13:43:47 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1581)
[13:43:47 WARN]:        at me.botsko.prism.actionlibs.ActionsQuery.delete(ActionsQuery.java:346)
[13:43:47 WARN]:        at me.botsko.prism.purge.PurgeTask.run(PurgeTask.java:84)
```

And immediately ran `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`, which shows only one active purge query:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMbqQ.png

[Link to code mentioned in error](https://github.com/prism/Prism/blob/master/src/main/java/me/botsko/prism/actionlibs/ActionsQuery.java#L346)

Comment: How could I determine what's causing the locks? I had assumed the purge query was the one causing the lock because of the report. The application allows users to run lookups (select queries), maybe those are locking too many rows?

Comment: [For InnoDB and BDB tables, MySQL uses table locking only if you explicitly lock the table with LOCK TABLES. For these storage engines, avoid using LOCK TABLES at all](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html) - The code/application is doing it explicitly, and for innodb it's generally not recommended to do so.

Comment: According to the docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html) the only queries we're running that are locking the tables should be these delete queries. The only thing we do besides this is INSERT, and SELECT.

Comment: The application is not locking tables unless JDBC is somehow doing this without my knowledge.

Comment: If that's true there are delete statements in parallel (with overlapping pk ranges?) - either way though I don't think there's enough info in the question for a 3rd party to help with this atm; would be quite important to identify for a given instance which statement is responsible for making the current delete statement wait.

Comment: How can I determine what's causing the delete statement to wait?  Our app only schedules the next delete statement when the current one is completed. There was a bug once that allowed multiple purge queries to run together but they were for different purges and that bug should be fixed.

Comment: With [show full processlist](http://serverfault.com/questions/36260/how-can-i-show-mysql-locks) probably.

Comment: I've added the error and processlist from a user who's hanging out in our irc channel and has this issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can find the source query that's blocking your DELETE by using the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.LOCK_WAITS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-lock-waits-table.html) and INNODB_TRX tables.

```
SELECT r.trx_id waiting_trx_id,  
       r.trx_mysql_thread_id waiting_thread,
       r.trx_query waiting_query,
       b.trx_id blocking_trx_id, 
       b.trx_mysql_thread_id blocking_thread,
       b.trx_query blocking_query
   FROM       information_schema.innodb_lock_waits w
   INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_trx b  ON  
    b.trx_id = w.blocking_trx_id
  INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_trx r  ON  
    r.trx_id = w.requesting_trx_id;
```

See more information at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-information-schema.html#innodb-information-schema-examples, under "Example 14.2 Identifying Blocking Transactions".

---

Re your comment and screenshot:

Because the `blocking_query` is NULL, this suggests to me that another thread finished its query, but is retaining its lock.

A transaction will retain its lock until the end of the transaction, even if it's no longer working on any given query.

You should COMMIT or ROLLBACK transactions promptly when they have finished their work. This will reduce the duration of locks, and reduce the chance of blocking other threads.

---

Another tip: it sounds like you have developed the same tool as [pt-archiver](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-archiver.html). For example:

```bsh
$ pt-archiver h=localhost,D=mydatabase,t=prism_data
    --purge --bulk-delete --commit-each --limit 1000 --where "epoch <= 1388566847"
```

Will loop over as many chunks as necessary, in 1000-row chunks, committing each time.

Comment: Thanks, will have users experiencing this issue run the query and see what results we get. The chunk-delete portion of the app is just a way to clear the db not the primary function and because it's distributed, had to be part of the app itself. Thanks!

Comment: A user had a locking issue and ran the query. This was his result: http://i.imgur.com/OOoeOMx.png

Comment: Regarding your update: I'm calling `commit` after building a batch query but I'm not sure how it could be left open. In java, we're calling `conn.setAutoCommit(false);`, adding some insert queries, and then calling `conn.commit();`. The only thing I could imagine is that a check for the connection being closed is preventing the commit from happening.  https://github.com/prism/Prism/blob/master/src/main/java/me/botsko/prism/actionlibs/RecordingTask.java#L238

Answer (score 1):

I have two crazy ideas (please be gentle with me):

**1. Add only one limit to the delete query**

The sql would look like this:

```
DELETE FROM prism_data WHERE prism_data.epoch <= '1388566847' limit 10000
```

Then repeat while ROW_COUNT() is > 0, only when ROW_COUNT()<= 0 change the id boundaries or time epoch, this should unlock the tables after deleting 10000 rows...(remember mysql is not allowing range while deleting like 10,20, it is only allowing a row count limit).
Keep in mind that epoch is not a PRIMARY KEY.

**2. Duplicate tables - might not work on "distributed" but this solution might help other people**

Maybe it sounds crazy...but I would do it plain and simple "redundancy style" (I know 50M is a big table, it's a storage vs speed issue), but performance wise with two tables should be faster when you delete...

insert in both, delete from the temp, and rename (is very fast), you only lock the heavy used table while renaming.

Let's say we have prism_data and prism_data_tmp and we insert/update/delete in both and select only from prism_data.

PURGE will work like this

```
DELETE FROM prism_data_tmp WHERE prism_data_tmp.epoch <= '1388566847';

RENAME table prism_data_tmp to prism_data_sw, prism_data to prism_data_tmp, prism_data_sw to prism_data;

/* switch the tables and reRun the query on the newly temp table to be up to date*/

DELETE FROM prism_data_tmp WHERE prism_data_tmp.epoch <= '1388566847';
```

I do not think is necessarily to **use primary key chunking** because you're deleting only from the tmp table which is not hevily selected...(only inserts and updates)

after 12 hours...repeat

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Unfortunately neither will work for our needs. We started with a `limit` clause but that doesn't constrain the locks properly and also made it harder to use certain conditions.